24.04 System Language Will Not Change
I am pretty new to Ubuntu so please bear over with me if stupid question. I have installed Jammy Jellyfish on a new computer to my girlfriend, but in the system settings it will not change the language from English to Norwegian. I have downloaded the Norwegian language pack, restarted the machine, selected the right language, but it still will not change from english to norwegian system wide. Anyone who may lead me in the right direction? (I try to install 24.04 to my girlfriend who do not speak/understand english and must have Norwegian language to use Ubuntu)  Anyone?

Did you try to select Norwegian as the system language and keyboard at the time of installing Ubuntu? Please edit your question and add this information.

I faced into similar issue. I updated the system from 23.XXX o 24.04 (see the pic) and since then I can switch the language, but the "language icon" doesn't change when I do it with hotkey. There is an important thing that I replaced default hotkeys using Tweaks config app/plugin to Alt+Shift.
I have 2 layouts for keyboard (Eng and Rus), but the system (main) language is English.
The system attrs:


I found that it is Wayland issue somehow. If I switch to "Ubuntu" (X11) instead "Ubuntu Wayland" on Login screen then I can change system language. (on Wayland I can't).
